# Как создать свечной график, используя только matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

У меня проблема с отображением vlines в том месте, где тело свечи очень маленькое. Может кто уже решал подобную проблему.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)

fig.set_size_inches(12.0, 6.0)

axs.vlines(df.index, df['Start_g'], df['End_g'], color='green', linestyle='-', lw=10)
axs.vlines(df.index, df['Start_r'], df['End_r'], color='red', linestyle='-', lw=10)

axs.vlines(df.index, df['Low_g'], df['High_g'], color='green', linestyle='-', lw=1)
axs.vlines(df.index, df['Low_r'], df['High_r'], color='red', linestyle='-', lw=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался установить dpi на 200 fig.set_dpi(200), это помогает, но свечи перекрывают друг друга. Не хотелось бы менять dpi, размер фигуры меняется и размеры `ticklabels` да и свечи громоздкими становятся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отображения тела свечи я использовал Rectangle, а для отображения минимума и максимума Line2D. Входные данные должны быть **pandas.DataFrame** (`df`) с колонками `Open` `High` `Low` `Close`

```
df = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_collection(df):
    
    l = len(df)

    grid = []
    height = []
    colors = []
    
    for i in range(l):
        if df.loc[i, 'Close'] > df.loc[i, 'Open']:
            grid.append([i, df.loc[i, 'Open']])
            height.append(df.loc[i, 'Close'] - df.loc[i, 'Open'])
            colors.append('green')
        elif df.loc[i, 'Close'] < df.loc[i, 'Open']:
            grid.append([i, df.loc[i, 'Close']])
            height.append(df.loc[i, 'Open'] - df.loc[i, 'Close'])
            colors.append('red')
    grid = np.array(grid)

    patches = []
    lines = []
    width = 0.5
    
    for i in range(l):
        
        rect = mpatches.Rectangle(grid[i]-[width/2, 0.0], width, height[i])
        patches.append(rect)
        line = mlines.Line2D([i, i], [df.loc[i, 'Low'], df.loc[i, 'High']], lw=0.75, color=colors[i])
        lines.append(line)

    collection = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.cm.hsv)
    collection.set_facecolors([colors[i] for i in range(l)])
    collection.set_linewidth(1.0)
    collection.set_edgecolors([colors[i] for i in range(l)])
    
    return collection, lines

collection, lines = create_collection(df)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figwidth(640)
fig.set_figheight(320)
fig.set_size_inches(12.0, 6.0)

axs.add_collection(collection)
[axs.add_line(lines[i]) for i in range(len(df))]

plt.axis('auto')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: _Это не вопрос.